# Compare datetime in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime, comparison

I have this statement :

```
SELECT t1.* FROM pos t1
        INNER JOIN pos_visit t2
           ON t2.pos_id = t1.id_pos
        INNER JOIN roadmap t3
           ON t3.id_roadmap = t2.roadmap_id
WHERE t3.id_roadmap ='rmp100000000000000020121206114347690'
    AND datetime(t1.lastChangedDate) > datetime(t3.lastChangedDate);
```

and I get no such a function  `datetime`.

I mention that I tried `strftime` too. All this functions works fine on sqLiteBrowser, but in Android, it is not working. I tried `julianday` and I don't get any error, but the Select is not returning the correct values (it should return one registration and it does not return anything)

Any idea where is the problem ?

Comment: How defined `lastChangedDate` in `pos` table? I thing you don't need of `datetime` just use
`AND t1.lastChangedDate > t3.lastChangedDate;`

Answer (score 1):

you can solve the problem this way:

I store datetimes as YYYYMMDDHH. so I can execute stempel >= '2012120612' and stempel <= '2012122412'

Another trick is to save the date as long values(lDate.getTime() in java). so you can do this:

stempel >= 1231243154123123 and stempel <= 1231234235526265